# Implementing (network) search android

Tags: android, search, searchview, searchable

I'm lost.

For the last few days, I'm trying to understand what will be the best way to implement a network search in my Android app.

I would like to keep the MVVM architecture but if it's too much to ask, I'm ready to consider the alternatives.

I need to be able to search in pages.

A good example\guide will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your API and your amount of data (and your requirements). For example, if you can cache all data locally because it's ~20000 items, then you could even query locally from SQLite and display that. Then it won't be done with a network call and works offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android's Paging Library, you can accomplish a paged network search, and update a RecyclerView with your results.

Let's assume you have an API which we can use to invoke a search query. This would be backed by a [DataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/DataSource.html) you would implement, which would provide new pages of results as you scroll.

```
interface MySearchApi {
    fun search(query: String, count: Int): PagedList<SearchResult>
}
```

What we get back is a [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList), which is updated as more search results are loaded. We aren't wrapping this in an Rx Observable or a LiveData object, because in this case we don't expect loaded data to change.  If you were querying some kind of real time service which could have results change at any time, you might want to consider that.

We can publicize this paged list or LiveData from our ViewModel object, and build a PagedListAdapter subclass which will update a RecyclerView with the new data as it is loaded.

```
class MySearchAdapter() :
        PagedListAdapter<SearchResult, SearchResultViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchResultViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val concert: SearchResult? = getItem(position)

        // Note that "searchResult" is a placeholder if it's null.
        holder.bindTo(searchResult)
    }

    companion object {
        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object :
                DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Concert>() {
            // Concert details may have changed if reloaded from the database,
            // but ID is fixed.
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldSearchResult: SearchResult,
                    newSearchResult: SearchResult) = oldSearchResult.id == newSearchResult.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldSearchResult: SearchResult,
                    newSearchResult: Concert) = newSearchResult == newSearchResult
        }
    }
}
```

Wiring this up with a RecyclerView is done as you normally would any other Adapter and RecyclerView, and your PagedList should be notifying your DataSource whenever it requires a new page of data.

You can read more about the Pagination Architecture [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).

Comment: Thank you Alex. Actually I already have that working with the search. My problem starts with search on type, I don't want to have a network call on every type but wait a bit to see if the user typed another character or deleted. Like in RxJave with debounce, another important thing is to always display the latest result on the list.

Comment: Debounce would be a great way to accomplish that.  On each character typed, you can emit the text in your input.  After debounce timeout, you notify your model of the change. You can then emit a new search query, and replace your old pagedList with this new one (in which case I'd use the aforementioned LiveData<PagedList>>, and then observe it where appropriate).

Sorry, your original question sounded like you hadn't attempted anything yet.  In the future, it's best to describe what you've done so far.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually my problem is that I don't know how to debounce before I emitting my input to the datasource. The integration between Paging Library  and RxJava is what I struggling the most

Comment: So I think we can break this into 3 parts: Debounce, Updating the DataSource, and displaying the data.

You can do a debounce within the VM, perhaps utilizing a publishsubject.  When your input is changed, add the full input text through the publishsubject.  You can debounce this and subscribe, and when you get a new value you can request a new PagedList from your API.  Then, you can update your ViewModel's LiveData<PagedList>, which can then update the adapter's implementation.

You'd just need to observe this livedata, say in activity, and update the adapter when you get a new value.

Comment: Wow Alex, thanks a lot for replying so fast. Any chance you have an example?